# Select field label for a value

Tags: entities

is there a way to get the label of a value from a select field?
I mean that if my select field has options like:

key1|label1
Key2|label2

how can I get label1 in my node--*.tpl.php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list_allowed_values()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7).

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
```

For reference [field_info_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7)